# How are non-bijective morphisms "reversed"?

Tags: category-theory

I have the following general definitions:

- 1) The dual graph $G^\mathrm{op}$ of a graph $G$ is obtained by simply reversing all the arrows (e.g. by interchanging the roles of the source and target maps $\sigma,\tau:E_G\to V_G$).
- 2) The dual category $C^\mathrm{op}$ of a category $C$ is simply the dual graph of the category, so again, we just reverse the arrows.
- 3) A monomorphism is a morphism $f\in\mathrm{Mor}(C)$ such that for each pair or morphisms $g,h\in\mathrm{Mor}(C)$, the equality $f\circ g=f\circ h$ implies $g=h$.
- 4) An epimorphism

  - 4a) is an epimorphism is a morphism $f$ such that for each pair or morphisms $g,h\in\mathrm{Mor}(C)$, the equality $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies $g=h$.
  - 4b) or, equivalently, is a morphism $f$ whose dual $f^\mathrm{op}$ is a monomorphism.

Please correct me if these standard definitions are not correctly stated.

Let's take a morphism $f:A\to B$ in the category $(\mathrm{Sets})$, and let's say that $f$ is surjective but not injective.

What is the dual morphism $f^\mathrm{op}$ of $f$? In other words, if I want to use definition 4b) to check if it's an epi, how can I show that its dual is a mono? Or, in other words, how are duals of non-bijective morphisms defined in $(\mathrm{Sets})$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've already given the definition: the category $\text{Set}$ can be thought of as a giant graph whose objects are sets and morphisms are functions, and taking the dual category just means we reverse the direction of every arrow. This is a purely formal procedure, and in particular even if $C$ has some interpretation in terms of sets and functions (that is, a functor $C \to \text{Set}$), that doesn't mean $C^{op}$ will.

So $f^{op}$ is just $f$ again, but with its source and target reversed, as a purely formal object. The fact that the dual of an epi is a mono is again a purely formal consequence of the fact that the two definitions (in terms of canceling) are dual. And bijectivity has nothing to do with it: even if $f$ happens to be a bijection, $f^{op}$ has nothing to do with $f^{-1}$. The two morphisms can't even be compared because they live in two different categories, namely $\text{Set}^{op}$ and $\text{Set}$.

Now it happens that $\text{Set}^{op}$ *can* be given an interpretation in terms of sets and functions, but it's not trivial to give and it doesn't come automatically from being an opposite category.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! However, I'm not sure how to prove a statement like *epis in the category (Sets) are exactly the surjections* using definition 4b), if the dual of a morphism is something formal, and not something I can identify as an injective function. Is it even possible to prove this that way?

Comment: Speculating on that final paragraph, I guess the most natural way to view $\mathbf{Set}^{op}$ as concrete over $\mathbf{Set}$ is to declare that the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Set}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}$ is the contravariant powerset functor. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: @Bass: no, that statement is not a formal statement and really needs to be proved as a fact about sets and functions, although it's not hard.

Comment: @goblin: yes, but you can do better and even identify exactly what extra structure this equips the "underlying sets" with. One way to say it is that $\text{Set}^{op}$ is equivalent to the category of profinite Boolean rings. A more traditional way to say it is that it's equivalent to the category of complete atomic Boolean algebras.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yep, that makes a lot of sense (except that I haven't yet gotten my head around profinite things, so that part is kind of going over my head at the moment.)

Comment: @goblin have you tried looking up the word? It's very simple, just an inverse limit of finite discrete topological rings.

Comment: To show that epis in the category (Sets) are exactly the surjections using definition 4b) is most easily done by pointing out that a monic in Set^op is an epi in Set (which is a purely formal argument that works in any category whatever), and then give the usual proof using the categorical definition of epi that an epi in Set is surjective. It really doesn't make sense to try to use the fact that Set^op has a concrete representation to prove it -- it is bound to be much more complicated doing it that way.

Comment: @KevinCarlson, sure, but how in the world does one gain any intuition for these things?

Comment: So given $C(X,Y)$, I'm guessing there's some reason why it's important to distinguish between $C(Y,X)$ and $C^{op}(X,Y)$? I'm definitely missing something her.